# Calling Template-Function of Parent-Class from Derived Class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, crtp

I have a very specific question (dont mind asking why i want this, it would be very complicated to explain it)

I want to call a Template-Function from a parent-Class, which indirectly calls the Destructor of the Child-Class

I tried to implement this code:

**The Parent Class:**

```
template <typename BaseType>         //OpcUa_NodeInstance.h
class OpcUa_NodeInstance
{
public:
    template <typename BaseTypee, unsigned PrefixID>
    static void deleteType(unsigned int ObjID);

};

template <typename BaseType> // OpcUa_NodeInstance.cpp
template <typename BaseTypee, unsigned PrefixID>
void OpcUa_NodeInstance<BaseType>::deleteType(unsigned ObjID)
{
    if (ObjID == PrefixID)
    {
        NodeManagerRoot* pNodeManagerRoot = NodeManagerRoot::CreateRootNodeManager();
        auto dummyTypeInstance = new BaseTypee(UaNodeId(PrefixID, 2),
            UaString("Dummy_AutomationDomainType"), 2, pNodeManagerRoot);
        delete dummyTypeInstance;
    }
}
```

**The Child Class:**

```
class AutomationDomainTypeBase: // AutomationDomainTypeBase.h
    public OpcUa_NodeInstance<AutomationDomainTypeBase>
{
   public:
          template <typename BaseType, unsigned int PrefixID> 
          static void deleteType(unsigned int ObjID);
}
```

the problem is that visual studio shows a linker error

```
Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl AutomationDomainTypeBase::deleteType<class AutomationDomainTypeBase,1018>(unsigned int)"
```

*AutomationDomainTypeBase*

I'm guessing the Compiler cannot recognize that the Implemetation of *deleteType* is already in the Parent-Class. Because of having more then 400 child-Classes, i'm looking for a way of not implementing this function in all children.

Comment: The code you provided does compile fine with me, using ms vc14.

Comment: @shrike thanks, i forgot to include the Parent.h, I edited my Topic. Can you help me with the Linker error?

Comment: `template <typename BaseType>
template <typename BaseTypee`
Is it a mistype here or in your code? First it's Type and next it's Typee.

Comment: @bipll if i name the class template and the function template the same i get this error: *c3860*

Comment: Oh, sure, those two are different type variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to define the child class without including first definition of the parent class.

If I compile your code with both definitions, I got no compilation error.

But if I compile only the child class definition, without including parent class definition first, I got:

```
1>Time\Time_Test.cpp(625): error C2504: 'OpcUa_NodeInstance' : classe de base non définie
1>Time\Time_Test.cpp(625): error C2143: erreur de syntaxe : absence de ',' avant '<'
```

just like you.

**Note**: make sure `OpcUa_NodeInstance<BaseType>::deleteType()` template member function is properly defined (and not declared only) in the header file where you define `OpcUa_NodeInstance` template class. Otherwise, you will get an undefined symbol at linking.

---

New edit:

OK, I think I got what you need: just do not declare/define `AutomationDomainTypeBase::deleteType()` if you want only `OpcUa_NodeInstance::deleteType()` to be used for any child class.

Also, I think you can simply define `OpcUa_NodeInstance::deleteType()` as follows:

```
template <typename BaseType>
class OpcUa_NodeInstance
{
public:
    template <unsigned PrefixID>
    static void deleteType(unsigned int ObjID);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to include the Parent.h, I edited my Topic. Can you help me with the Linker error?

Comment: @Pepelee: see the final "Note" in my answer, you'll get the answer; implementation of `OpcUa_NodeInstance<BaseType>::deleteType()` must be implemented in the header file too.

Comment: but i already did implement it in the header file, as you can see in the start of my topic (first snippet)

Comment: :-) The problem is about inheriting this kind of template function, i did research for *crtp* but could not find an answer..

Comment: @Pepelee: the CRTP looks correct; what's wrong is that the template member function is only declared in the child class header, and not defined/implemented; add an implementation of this template member function in the child class header (just like for the parent class template member function), if a generic implementation is possible. Otherwise, you may have to implement some specializations...

Comment: so i have to implement the whole function in the child class header? what's the purpose of inheariting it from the Parent-Class then, if i have to copy the whole implementation in the child header?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111005/discussion-between-pepelee-and-shrike).

Comment: @Pepelee: sorry, not too much time; see my new edits; may help.

Comment: thank you very much, i solved the linker error: i implemented the function directly in the OpcUa_NodeInstance.h file, instead of just declaring it. the OpcUa_NodeInstance.cpp is not used at all, now